# Showing posts from different categories and from custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, pre-get-posts

On my main page, I want to show posts from 3 categories, and 1 custom post type.

Is there a way to get them together in one `pre_get_posts` function? Or do I need to query separately - once for the CPT and once for the posts from specific categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after on post from category a, one from category b,  another form category c and then finally a custom post type - each of these would have to be a separate query.

Think of these as 'secondary queries' - (the primary query being what lands you on the home page). So you'll want use seperate instances of `WP_Query` (see this [related post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/9364)).

E.g.

```
$post_from_cat_a  = new WP_Query(array( 
    'category__name' => array('a'), 
    'posts_per_page'=> 1
));
if( $post_from_cat_a->have_posts() ){
    while( $post_from_cat_a->have_posts() ): $post_from_cat_a->the_post();
         //Display output here
    endwhile;
}

$post_from_cat_b  = new WP_Query(array( 
    'category__name' => array('b'), 
    'posts_per_page'=> 1
));
if( $post_from_cat_b->have_posts() ){
  ...
  ...
```

etc. Don't forget to call `wp_reset_postdata();` at the end.